# How to solve drastic brightness change when using cv2.seamlessclone?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, blending

I try to use cv2.seamlessclone to merge face image **ori_img** and skin **mh_skin**.

I want to replace the non-face area with skin by this operation,

Here's my code:

```
br = cv2.boundingRect(tight_mask[:, :, 0])
centerOfBR = (br[0] + br[2] // 2, br[1] + br[3] // 2)
blend_img = cv2.seamlessClone((ori_img * (tight_mask / 255)).astype(np.uint8), mh_skin,
                              tight_mask, centerOfBR, flags=cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
```

However, I got image with drastic brightness change.

After do that, I got an image with drastic brightness change.

I attempt to use other flags like MIXCLONE and MONOCHROME_TRANSFER, but it seems not work. Besides, when I try to use a smaller mask, the brightness change may be better.

Comment: You could try to adjust brightbess by first measuring mean brightness in the target image and rescale the brightness in the source image accordingly.

Comment: It seems that only the boundary has strong light, but it cause the whole image wrong. I'm sorry that maybe I don't describe the question clearly but I can't upload image because I'm new to this community